# Getting the path to the game through the registry + launching the process in the final folder of the path by pressing the button C # + WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, registry, exe, launch

Trying to read the installation path of the game (InstallLocation) from one section in the registry (SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 4000), write it to another section (SOFTWARE\WpfApp) in key (NewInstallPath), and then find the exe file with the game in the installation path of the game, and run

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace wpfApp
{

    /// \<summary\>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// \</summary\>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using var localMachineRegistry = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            using var gmodAppRegistry = localMachineRegistry.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 4000", false);
            string readInstallPath = gmodAppRegistry.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
    
            RegistryKey InstallPath = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WpfApp", SetValue("NewInstallPath", readInstallPath)); //launcher partition path
        }
    }

}
```

As soon as I did not try to implement it, but even according to the documentation it comes out crooked. That value is recorded, but the game does not start, then nothing is recorded at all and does not start.

Comment: You realise there's a manifest file for each steam game? I think that has install path in it. in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps appmanifest_<appid>.acf  My understanding is that this is used by steam to start games and to apply patches.

Comment: Damn didn't even know about it. Thank you

Comment: Not sure exactly what you intend but moving a game is kind of tricky. Why do you want to? I might have some more advice.

Comment: I don't want to move the game. I want to find the game installation path (folder), find the exe game process there and run it with the parameter. All this, as I understand it, can be done through the registry using Process and Registry in c#

**maybe I'm somewhere not so expressed in technical terms, as a little noob) I apologize in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're intended to run steam games is through steam itself.

Steam automatically updates the app etc.

There is a rungameid command line parameter which allows you to run a game ( somewhat ) directly.

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam" steam://rungameid/281990
```

And... eventually as my login credentials install etc etc were stale...

[image]

Steam may be in C:\Program Files instead.

The nice-ish aspect of this is that you just need to check where steam is and know your game app id.

You can also run a game that isn't currently installed this way. There will of course be quite a delay as steam goes and gets everything for you.

I think some games are not so straight forward that they "just" have the one exe. Some have launchers ( ours does ).